# Vertical scroll of ImageView and GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I have layout with ImageView and GridView below.
I need to implement vertical scroll of ImageView and GridView together.
I try to use ScrollView but no result because ScrollView can't have GridView  child item.

This is code of my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widgets_wallpaper_text_background_height"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_widgets_under_text" />

       <GridView
            android:id="@+id/menu_widgets_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget_wallpaper_grid_margine_top"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/widgets_wallpaper_row_spaces"
            android:listSelector="@null"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix it actually scroll bar can't have more than one child at a time. Try it..

Hope it will work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_inner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_inner_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/menu_widgets_grid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:listSelector="@null"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```